# Why MongoDB bulkWrite doesn't support insertMany?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB [`db.collection.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) supports [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany) and [deleteMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-deleteonemany).

Is there any reason not supporting **insertMany**?

Comment: The biggest reason as to "why" is in fact the implementation is in fact the "other way around" as **ALL** MongoDB CRUD operations are in fact implemented using `bulkWrite` ( or depending on language API, probably the underlying "Bulk" initialize methods). So `insertMany()` does *internally* call what is effectively `bulkWrite`. The easy way to view this is either do `db.collection.insertMany` in the shell **without** the brackets `()`. This dumps the JavaScript implementation where you see the "Bulk" methods being used. Same for other CRUD functions. Well not the `R` or `find()`.

Comment: You can also view your source language API code and see very similar implementation as to what is visible in the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no authoritative figure in this regard, but I'd assume that *update* and *delete* operations work with a *query* which may match none, one or many existing documents. Hence it's useful to distinguish whether you want to apply the change to *one* or *many* documents, both from an efficiency standpoint (you can stop as soon as you found one) and from a logic standpoint (you only want to manipulate the first match).

For insert operations that doesn't apply; an insert  operation inserts one document, and especially in the context of a bulk write, inserting multiple documents is simply done by passing multiple *insert-one* operations to `bulkWrite`; no need for a redundant *insert-many* operation.

Comment: To be more "authoritative", the actual `insertMany()` implementation ( and even `insertOne()` for that matter ) actually calls the "Bulk API" internally. This has been the practice since the "Bulk API" was introduced with MongoDB 2.6, and therefore is even true of the now deprecated `insert()`. But the basic standpoint of the *"why"* on all cases is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any sense by providing the insertMany operation as we can do this with multiple insertOne in bulkOperation() and another point is at the time of update/delete operation the filter condition you are providing might be applied on one or more documents in the collection. Which the help of updateOne or updateMany you can decide if you want to update only one(first matching) or all documents satisfying the filter condition. The same thing applies for delete as well, but in case of the insert, there is only one document always unlike update or delete where multiple documents can be there.

However, they can provide insertMany(Array of document) but as we can see they are limiting only one object for all available operation for the shake of simplicity. Either in updateOne/updateMany/insertOne you only can pass object not an array.

Comment: updateOne also doesn't support multi-option available in update() method which is supported by updateMany in buikWrite().